# CodeIgniter Database Rows Into Arrays To Use By Parser For Views Built-In Template

Tags: arrays, database, codeigniter, parsing, templates

1) My original `settings` table design:

```
-------------------------------------------
site_name | site_slogan | site_url
-------------------------------------------
Company   | This rocks! | http://localhost/
-------------------------------------------
```

However, I would like to redesign so I can explicitly put different datatypes like char(255) or varchar(512), or maybe INT in the future for each row:

```
-------------------------------
name        | value
-------------------------------
site_name   | Company
site_slogan | This rocks!
site_url    | http://localhost/
site_phone  | 123465798
-------------------------------
```

In my controller, I would like to use `$this->parser->parse('page',$data);` but I don't know how to put the result of my database query into arrays in a loop so that in my Views I can use them like this:

`<a href="{site_url}">{site_name} - {site_slogan}</a>`

### Edit:

This the result of `$data = $this->db->select("*")->from('settings')->get()->result_array();` from the feedback I received.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => site_name
            [value] => My Name
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => site_tagline
            [value] => My Tagline
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => site_url
            [value] => My URL
        )

)
```

So this is how I parse and make them usable in views `{site_name}` `{site_tagline}` `{site_url}` .

```
$data = array(
   'site_name' => $data['0']['value'],
   'site_tagline' => $data['1']['value'],
   'site_url' => $data['2']['value']
);
$this->parser->parse('page', $data);
```

Comment: try this store result to one variable
`$result = $this->db->select("*")->from('settings')->get()->result_array();`
after that
`$data = array(
        'site_url' =>$result['site_url']
);`
then pass this data variable to your view template

Comment: `Message: Undefined index: site_url`

Comment: print your `$result` what you got?

Comment: `Message: Array to string conversion`

Comment: Ofc it will throw that because you are trying to `echo` an array, try `var_dump` tho @RangkaKacang

Comment: Silly me, thank you for the heads up regarding `var_dump`. I'm new to PHP, anyway here are the results `array(1) { ["name"]=> array(3) { [0]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(9) "site_name" ["value"]=> string(12) "My Title" } [1]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(12) "site_tagline" ["value"]=> string(44) "My Tagline" } [2]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(8) "site_url" ["value"]=> string(30) "My URL" } } }`

Comment: to print array 
`echo "<pre>"; print_r($result); die;`

Comment: hope it help you

Comment: I have edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

You could assign the `$data` values to a new array and pass the new array instead :

```
foreach ($data as $key => $cfg) {
    $new_data[$cfg['name']] = $cfg['value'];
}
$this->parser->parse('page', $new_data);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I’m looking for. Looping the data from my database and put them in an array so the rows from the name column will be used as the template parser tag which will then return the matching value column respectively.

Comment: I have accepted your answer. I can't imagine declaring every single settings manually just to make them parseable, what if there are 100 rows but thankfully for your single line of code, I can logically solve the problem the way I want it to be. Btw, I appreciate if you explain to me what does `foreach ($a as $b => $c) { $d[$e['col1'] = $f['col2']]; }` do in human language?

Comment: Thanks, glad I could help :). Actually it's `foreach ($a as $b => $c) { $d[$c['col1'] = $c['col2']]; }`, where on each iteration of `$a` array we assign a new array named `$d` which containing a pair of key (from `$c['col1']` value) and value (from `$c['col2']` value).