# PHP Array Foreach() Pass Variable From Database to CodeIgniter Template Parser

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, parsing, foreach

This is my database table (previously, I used a vertical design but due to lack of datatype support, I changed to horizontal design):

```
+-----------+-------------------+
| site_name | site_url          |
+-----------+-------------------+
| Awesome   | http://localhost/ |
+-----------+-------------------+
```

Controller:

```
public function index() {
   $data = $this->db->select("*")->from('settings')->get()->result_array();
   $new_data = $data['0'];
   $this->parser->parse('default/header.php', $new_data);
}
```

View:

`<a href="{site_url}">{site_name}</a>`

The above $data will print:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [site_name] => Awesome
            [site_url] => http://localhost/
        )
)
```

I think my controller's codes look stupid. Is there a better way to loop using `foreach()` to pass the key and value automatically so I can use it with CodeIgniter's template parser such as `{site_name}` `{site_url}`?

For additional reference, you can see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49191713/codeigniter-database-rows-into-arrays-to-use-by-parser-for-views-built-in-templa), it's related but not a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

Controller

```
public function index() {
  $settings = $this->db->get('settings')->first_row();
  $this->parser->parse('default/header.php', $settings);
}
```

View

```
<a href="{site_url}">{site_name}</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

your current code will work until you have one row, how about if you have many rows, this code will not work on that situation you will need some loops like foreach.

And you can keep your database manipulation in your model instead of controller.

otherwise that looks good not stupid. everybody has their own way to write code.

Comment: ok, thanks but who the heck downvoted me without a proper explanation, just because i need opinions... i need to loop the columns not row, do you have any ideas? and yes regarding the models i will do so, i'm just testing and still at learning phase and wrote this as an example.. btw, my table will only have 1 row because it's a horizontal table to store my settings/configs.. tq

Comment: everybody has their own perceptions regarding questions, just ignore them. they cannot ban you for asking questions they can just down vote you. its normal in stackoverflow

Comment: there is no point to loop columns you will get entire row whenever you run the query so there will be nothing for looping.

Comment: @vikrant You can get [suspended](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) for several reasons (manually by moderators and/or Stack Exchange Employees) and there are also automatic question/answer bans if your posts are not well-recieved (all or majority of them have downvotes).

Comment: ok tq vikrant and @chade_ that sounds scary.. it seems like this isn't a place for newbie to ask question, i will find an alternative then...

Comment: @RangkaKacang No, this is the right place, but there are harsh penalties if rules are broken or tried to be bypassed. That's not the case here. Your question is completely valid here, no matter what your skill-level is. Also, don't get frightened what I said about bans, they are heighlyunlikely to get if you continue your way like this